# What is default username and password for WebLogic server 10.3.6 admin console?

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I have installed Oracle WebLogic server 10.3.6. To install it, I have to provide a password for WebLogic user. Is there any other admin user and/or any default password for the admin user?

If exists, I have to disable or removed them for security reason. Please help me experts.